# Comparator outputs negative voltage when Vcc- is grounded

Tags: pcb, comparator

EDIT: Clarified the output I’m seeing at the oscilloscope.

EDIT 2: I've changed the input signal to be a different square wave with V_high = 2V and V_low = 0.5V. It seems that I may have a hidden connection between all the ports as I am seeing the same square wave from all the ports, even the ground port. At the Vcc+ port where I supply a 5V_DC, I'm seeing the square wave superimposing on the supply voltage. Thanks for suggesting ways to test and highlighting the issue regarding input voltage being beyond the limit.

Moving forward, how can I improve the design so that I don't end up getting this hidden connection? (It's on a PCB)

1. Make sure traces don't criss-cross and separate them as far as possible?
2. Separate the power and signal ports as far as possible?

Side note, have I correctly implemented the pull up resistor?

---

I'm testing out a comparator (TS880ICT) where I connect the following pins as follows:

- Non-inverting pin via the 'signal out port'  - square wave 4Vpp centered at 0V
- Inverting pin via the 'threshold' port - ground
- Vcc+ - 5V
- Vcc- -ground
- Output via the 'OUT' port - passed a pull up resistor of 1k ohm. Pulled up to Vcc+

I'm expecting to see one half of the square wave but I am seeing a slightly attenuated square wave instead. I suspect that I may have pulled up the output incorrectly. The graph below is the output after the pull up resistor, at the OUT port.

Can someone advise if this is so?

[image]

This is the circuit I'm working with.

[image]

Comment: Looks like your oscilloscope input is set to AC (coupled) meaning the average voltage will be zero. Can you confirm?

Comment: It’s set to DC, 1M ohm. The red square wave is the output at the OUT port. Sorry I didn’t make it clear. I’ve edited the original post

Comment: Ok, can you make sure the probe ground reference is actually connected to  ground and try channel B to ensure there isn't some kind of math going on. Your screen capture is quite uninformative- does "show details" provide more info?

Comment: "Non-inverting pin via the 'signal out port' - square wave 4Vpp centered at 0V" So from -2V to +2V? -2V is way outside the absolute maximum ratings for this device.

Comment: If you are pulling the input negative, you are outside the operating area for this device.  Look at the "Input Voltage Range" on your datasheet

Comment: Your question lacks too many details. Scope settings, values

Answer (score 1):

To understand your confusion, view each node and check if it conforms to the specification and understand if there are any hidden ESD protection diodes.

If not , then linear superposition applies.